# xcode tabelview cellview not showing only if pressed once

Tags: ios, xcode

So i have a tabelview where i show in cell's an json array , i added

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

and now i have to press a cell to show the actually content ...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier   forIndexPath:indexPath] ;





    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    cell.textLabel.text = [theArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.backgroundColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"dbdcd7"];
    cell.textLabel.textColor = [self colorWithHexString:@"d74032"];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [theArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


    return cell;
}
```

Here is an image of what i am trying to say the white cells are not touched and the gray ones are touched http://oi57.tinypic.com/idhqaq.jpg

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense. Either dequeue a reusable cell or allocate a cell (preferably the former because it is more efficient) but don't do both. Your code "throws away" the dequeued cell

Comment: I'm unclear what your problem is. Is something not displaying? Is the wrong information not displaying? And if this is something to do with cell selection, where is your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method? Also, as @Paulw11 pointed out your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` needs fixing.

Comment: @RoboticCat , on every cell is a white overlay color , and only if i touch the cell it shows me what's underneath the overlay

Comment: `1.` Fix your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` as per @Paulw11 suggestion and update your question with the corrected code. `2.` Post your `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method. `3.` Clarify your problem - should the text always be shown or should text only be shown when you touch a cell. You are still not clearly stating the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete this:

```
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

And set the cell style in the storyboard selecting the cell from the editor, and in the right panel, change the style from default to Subtitle.

Comment: The UitableviewCellStyle is added programatically

Comment: Why do you want to change the style programmatically?

Comment: Your tableView might have problems because it contains multiple and more important different cells with the same reuseIdentifier. if `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:` does not raise an exception it means there is a valid prototype cell registered for that reuseIdentifier. The registering is done either programmatically or in a storyboard. And that is exactly the place where the cell should be changed to the correct style.

Answer (score 0):

Normally you would get the cell this way:

```
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier   forIndexPath:indexPath] ;
   if ( cell == nil ) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
   }
```

Comment: Not necessary. [`dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:) will always return a valid cell. It will never return nil.

Comment: That has not always been the case when the table is created programmatically.

Comment: For that particular method it has. You are thinking about `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:`, without the `forIndexPath:` part at the end. That's the "old" (as in age, it's not deprecated and it's still useful) method, and it will return nil. When Apple introduced cell prototypes that can be registered with the tableView (either in storyboards or programmatically) they introduced the new method which is guaranteed to return a valid cell.

Comment: Doh! You are indeed correct @Matthew and I am sadly mistaken. Mea culpa.